# Angular modal with two submit buttons to trigger on "enter"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, submit

I have a search modal that has two buttons I want to trigger on pressing enter. There is the initial "Search" button, and then a final "Submit" button.

The user is in an Angular Modal, puts a name into a search field (During this time, the Submit button is disabled) and then would press the "Enter" key to initiate the search. The search populates a table, after which the user clicks on a name to select and then the Submit button is enabled, and now I want a keypress of "Enter" to submit the selection.

I can get the first "Enter" to run the search functionality, but I can't get the second press of "Enter" to initiate the Submit of the selection.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getNames(params)" value="Search">Search</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="Clear(params)">Clear</button>
```

And then once the list of names populates, the user selects one and then should be able to press "Enter" again to trigger the Submit button.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="OK()" ng-disabled="disableOK()"/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Using `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default "ng-click="OK()" g-disabled="disableOK()"></button>` Doesn't work here either.

I've looked everywhere since this seems like it would be a common problem, but I haven't seen a fix for this, mostly it's people with multiple buttons wanting to do different things on submit, not triggering with the "Enter" key.

Can I assign it to be the default when it becomes enabled?

Comment: Make sure you button is part of the form. Then use onsubmit event. Enter will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following what you are trying to do.. however, if I was trying to accomplish a form doing different things on a keypress I would do the following in my controller:

```
var keypressed = false;

$scope.keyPressedFunction = function() {    
    if (keypressed) {
      // do second thing
    } else {
      // do first thing
      keypressed = true
    }
}
```

Does this answer your question at all?